# You cant open eclipse because powerpc applications are no longer supported on mac

Tags: eclipse, dock

Not able to launch eclipse from the Dock. My operating system is Mac OS X 64 Bit.

The error says:

> You can't open the application "Eclipse" because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.

I have installed Eclipse from this link: 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx

Comment: Did you choose 32-bit or 64-bit version?

Comment: At the downlload page header, it states: `Mac OS X users please note: Eclipse requires Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) or greater.` Have you checked your Mac OS X version?

Comment: I've recently messed with Eclipse, having downloaded a 64bit version, and it works fine.

Comment: I downloaded 64 bit. Mine is OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: did someone found a solution to this? I have the same problem with Eclipse Juno.. the doc shows eclipse button with a cross sign on it and gives the same error when I try to launch. I have mac 10.8.3

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error when I used `sudo tar xzf` on the command line to extract the Eclipse package directly into `/Applications`. But when I followed [these instructions](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs5/install/eclipse-osx/), I was able to open the application without errors. Specifically:

1. In Finder, locate the folder containing the Eclipse tar.gz package.
2. Double-click the Eclipse tar.gz package to extract the application into the same folder.
3. Drag the Eclipse application into the Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason can be if you have moved the eclipse setup from where it is run. To verify, right click the icon at dock and choose Options -> Show in Finder. And Make sure Eclipse setup exists.  If not, copy setup to that location and try running.